# How can I invoke the WebView inspector automatically?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, android

I'm developing an application on Android. Whenever I recompile and deploy the app, I would like to easily open the Chrome WebView inspector.

Usually, I would do that by manually browsing to `chrome://inspect/#devices` and clicking the **inspect** link for my WebView instance.

[image]

Whenever the application is re-deployed, the inspector for the WebView will be closed (because the application is stopped on the device) and I have to re-open it manually. This is cumbersome and I would like to automate the process. Preferably by using Git Bash.

I can't even get the given site to open. When I run `chrome.exe "chrome://inspect/#devices"`, only the New Tab Page will be opened.